# regex : mark every match in the string and return the string edited with marks, Java

Tags: java, regex

Goal is to mark every match in the string with **brackets** and return the same string with each match **marked**

i.e.:

```
Pattern = "\\d+"
Text = "e3e3e"
wanted result = "e(3)e(3)e"
```

i tried :

```
while (matcher.find())
text = text.replace(match.group(), "(" + match.group() + ")");
```

but it replaces all matches over and over every time it finds a match

```
e3e3e => e((3))e((3))e instead of e(3)e(3)e
h4h444h = > h(4)h(4)(4)(4)h  instead of h(4)h(444)h
```

Comment: To build the replacement string, you have to use references to the whole match or eventual capture groups: `$0` for the whole match, `$1` for capture group 1, `$2` for capture group 2 etc. Also, you don't need to use `matcher.find` to perform a replacement. The replaceAll method suffice and proceed all the string by default. See examples in the Java manual.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte would appreciate it if you post a sample code

Comment: Just use `text=text.replaceAll("\\d+", "($0)");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace your matches with `($0)` where `$0` stands for the whole match:

```
String Pattern = "\\d+";
String Text = "e3e3e";
System.out.println(Text.replaceAll(Pattern, "($0)"));
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/oE2avU) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d5HX8X/1).

[Java *`Pattern`* docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) say that

> Group zero always stands for the entire expression.